# proving that a function that's continous on $[a, +\infty$) with an horizontal or oblique asymptote (at +$\infty$) is uniformally continious

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

here's how I tried this (I guess it must be wrong),
let's firstly prove the part about the horizontal one,

if there exists an horizontal asymptote $\implies \lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=k\in \mathbb{R} $ therefore, for the Heine-Cantor theorem the function f is uniformally continous on $[a,k] \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ , i'm stuck in here on how to prove it in $(k,+\infty)$

Comment: You should edit your question in such a way that it becomes self-contained.

Comment: i dont get the final part